# Missing resource error, in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, text, android-studio, textview

**Thank you everyone who posted an answer, I looked over most of them and they all seem to work! Sorry if I didn't mark your's the answer since I could only mark one. However all methods below worked for me. Much appreciated.**

Hi just a couple of things to know:

I created a new activity, very simple. Basically the function is to press the button on the `MainActivity` page which will redirect the user to a new page called display. Everything seems to be working fine except for two errors I keep on getting. The `android:id="@+id/"` and `android:layout_below="@+id/"` return that they are missing resource names.

Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/welcome_screen" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/g_button"
        android:id="@+id/g_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered that they really are missing resource names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give proper id to textview like below code

```
<TextView android:text="@string/welcome_screen" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/g_button"
    android:id="@+id/g_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/myText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your layout like this

```
<TextView android:text="@string/welcome_screen" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_temp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/g_button"
    android:id="@+id/g_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_temp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you actually describing the id tag and not giving the id to your views.Give your views some id.for eg :-

```
 <TextView android:text="@string/welcome_screen" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textAbc" //id cannot be left blank
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/g_button"
        android:id="@+id/g_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an ID name after the identifier, for example

```
android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
```

That ID is used to reference the View element from the code. For more details, see 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 1):

**Cause**

The layout has a `TextView` and below it a `Button` (atleast you want that), in the button you have `layout_below` which expects an id of the widget you want it to be below. But in your case you did not specify one. So you are getting this error.

**Solution**

Replace your xml with this the xml below.

```
<TextView android:text="@string/welcome_screen" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/g_button"
    android:id="@+id/below"
    android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 <TextView android:text="@string/welcome_screen"  
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/textview"   
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:textSize="24sp"
  android:textColor="#000000"/>

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/g_button"
android:id="@+id/g_button"
android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
android:layout_marginTop="121dp"   
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
```

Answer (score 1):

android:id="@+id/textview"

You can give id manually. If you want

Answer (score 1):

android:id="@+id/"

android:layout_below="@+id/"

Remove them your not doing anything with that attributes :

```
ID
```

Any View object may have an integer ID associated with it, to uniquely identify the View within the tree. When the application is compiled, this ID is referenced as an integer, but the ID is typically assigned in the layout XML file as a string, in the id attribute. This is an XML attribute common to all View objects (defined by the View class) and you will use it very often. The syntax for an ID, inside an XML tag is:

eg  `android:id="@+id/my_button"`

```
android:layout_below
```

Positions the top edge of this view below the given anchor view ID. Accommodates top margin of this view and bottom margin of anchor view.

Must be a reference to another resource, in the form "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form "?[package:][type:]name".

This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol layout_below.

```
android:layout_below="@+id/myText"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your xml file- the code for TextView , u have to give a name/id to it like below:

```
<TextView android:text="@string/welcome_screen" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/txtVw1"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="24sp"
android:textColor="#000000"/>
```